# Assets 2.0.5 problem when transferring database

Tags: database, assets

I am trying to install a local copy of my database on Mamp. But I am getting the following error in the exp_assets_folders table:

```
#1062 - Duplicate entry 'ee-0-' for key 'unq_source_type__source_id__full_path'
```

I saw another post with a similar problem but the answer says this was sorted in version 2.0.2. 
I am using Assets version 2.0.5. I am not using master config.

Thanks

Comment: What, exactly, are you doing when you run up against that error? Is that a full DB import? Using what software?

Comment: Hi Lisa I'm trying do do a Full DB import into MAMP.

Comment: What software are you using when you import the .sql file?  And is this into an otherwise blank database? Or is there data in there already?

Comment: phpmyadmin yes its a blank database

Comment: Is it possible to get a copy of the database? If so, please email it to support@pixelandtonic.com.  If it's very large (> 10meg) then please put it on something like Dropbox and send us a link to download. :)

Comment: Thank you! I see the same thing you do, using Sequel Pro to import.  How did you export this database? is there a chance the export itself is bad?

Comment: Hi Lisa, I tried a fresh export directly from the DB and that worked. I was using a Backup Pro version so it looks like the corruption has happened there. Thanks for your help

Comment: My pleasure!  Please post that as an answer and mark it as solved? Thank you, and glad you got this working!

Comment: Lisa, I've just run into this same problem. But of course in my case I used the Backup Pro 'Restore' function (see comment below on the answer). Not sure where the problem lies that but would really like to work with yourselves and/or Eric Lamb to get it sorted ASAP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was an issue with the Backup proish DB. 
Thanks for your help

Comment: I've just run into this problem myself. Using Backup Pro to restore a database, all my asset references to folders that are specified in a Focus Lab Config setup get lost...gone...#headdesk. How did you get around this?